# Possible explanation for why fully marine reptiles adapt to side to side tail motions while aquatic mamals develop mainly up and down tail motions?

Tags: evolution, fauna

To a certain extent, crocodiles and marine iguanas have also developed this behavior. Is this due to skeletal difference between mammals and reptiles? (This does not apply to marine mammals/reptiles that do not use tail strokes as a means of locomotion. Ex: sea turtles and seals)

[[image: mosasaurus[1][image: dolphin]

[image: iktheosaurus]

[image: dugong]

Comment: Perhaps it simply comes down to differences in the way reptilian and mammalian spines evolved, or their body shapes.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the worldbuilding element of the question. Is this a question about almost-convergent evolution? Or about how flippers work in water? Or something else?

Comment: This is not a question about Worldbuilding, it is about evolutionary biology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rewind to Fish

Fish are at the ancestral tree for all vertebrates (back-boned animals). They predominately swim by flexing their spine left-right (on the horizontal plane).

When amphibians and later lizards evolved they kept this same side-to-side motion because standing in a gravity well is hard.

Naturally it makes sense that those lineages that returned to an aquatic lifestyle maintained this same side-to-side motion. Why change what obviously just works?

With the exception of turtles

### Moving Fast on Land

Now waddling is not a great strategy for moving quickly on land. Not that it cannot be made effective... Crocodiles can move very quickly on land. Its just happens to use a lot of energy.

The main problem with a waddle is that it does not provide much opportunities for finding energy efficiency. A Side to side motion is orthogonal to gravity in most contexts. The solution is to place the legs directly underneath and flex the spine up and down. This setup lends itself to conserving energy in various *springs* up and down the leg, and in the spine itself.

This strategy is in use by dinosaurs (and their avian descendants), and Mammal-like Reptiles (and their mammalian descendants). Thus you can infer that when these creatures take back to an aquatic life-style they will flex their spines up and down. Looking at the world:

- Penguins (Avians)
- Gannets (Avians)
- Manatae (Mammals)
- Otters (Mammals)

With perhaps an exception for the Platypus which hunts on river beds where verticality is at a minimum. Thus making sense that it would prefer a more horizontal swimming style.

You mention that seals don't use a vertical stroke... Which is odd because they do indeed use vertical motion. Perhaps you could elaborate?

### So Why did fish choose side-to-side?

Probably because they were the only ones that survived - with the off chance that up-and-down just never existed.

If they did exist, up-and-down motion was probably a serious disadvantage:

- Perhaps a vertically flexing spine caused damage to the internal organs in the early chordates (when spines weren't bony, and rib cages just weren't in the health and safety manual).
- Perhaps the early lifestyle was in an environment that favoured horizontal motion (like the platypus).

That's a 10000ft explanation. You could go on for centuries figuring out each critical turning point that lead to the distinction between horizontal and vertical based spinal motion.

Comment: Nice response! By seals i meant they mainly used their hind legs to "kick" side to side, and do not use fully tail-based propulsion in water, such as cetaceans

Comment: `If they did exist, up-and-down motion was probably a serious disadvantage` See also flatfish -  e.g. [flounder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flounder) - that "tricked" evolution into an up-down movement of their tail while still maintaining essentially a left-right one relative to their spine.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Nice.